# How can I find a Substring in an SQl-Query=

Tags: sql, function, substring, pervasive

```
select * from "ParaListen" where Auftrag='235829/PAOrtsA'
```

How can I find a certain "Substring" in an Pervasive-statement?

```
Select select * from "ParaListen" where substr(Auftrag,8,?)='PAOrtsA'
```

I mean: which function shows the rest of the string after the "/" character?

Comment: What have you tried?  What version of Pervasive are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `substring`, I would suggest the `right` function.  With `right`, you can use the `position` or `locate` function to get the position of the `'/'` and get the rest of the string without needing to know the length of the remaining string.  Something like:

```
create table ParaListen1
 (f1 char(100), 
 auftrag char(14));

insert into ParaListen1
(f1, auftrag) values ('235829/PAOrtsA', '235829/PAOrtsA');

insert into ParaListen1
(f1, auftrag) values ('235829/PAOrtsB', '235829/PAOrtsB');

select position('/',auftrag),locate('/',auftrag), f1, auftrag from "ParaListen1" 
 where right(Auftrag,position('/',auftrag))='PAOrtsA'
```